# After login with facebook not get response from azure mobile service

Tags: facebook, azure, azure-mobile-services, xamarin.forms

I call to azure mobile service api from xamarin.forms  client app to get user info of login with facebook but I am unable to get user info.

Here is my code. please help.

```
Xamarin Forms code here:
async void OnFBLoginClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MobileServiceUser user;
    try
    {
        // The authentication provider could also be Facebook, Twitter, or Microsoft

        user = await DependencyService.Get<IMobileClient>().LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Facebook);
        MobileServiceClient client = new MobileServiceClient(Constants.ApplicationURL, Constants.ApplicationKey);

        try
        {
            var userInfo = await client.InvokeApiAsync("userInfo", HttpMethod.Get, null);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

.net backend azure mobile service code:

```
[AuthorizeLevel(AuthorizationLevel.User)]
    public async Task<JObject> Get()
    {
        ServiceUser user = this.User as ServiceUser;
        if (user == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("This can only be called by authenticated clients");
        }

        var identities = await user.GetIdentitiesAsync();
        var result = new JObject();
        var fb = identities.OfType<FacebookCredentials>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (fb != null)
        {
            var accessToken = fb.AccessToken;
            result.Add("facebook", await GetProviderInfo("https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" + accessToken));
        }

        var ms = identities.OfType<MicrosoftAccountCredentials>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (ms != null)
        {
            var accessToken = ms.AccessToken;
            result.Add("microsoft", await GetProviderInfo("https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me/?method=GET&access_token=" + accessToken));
        }
        return result;
    }

    private async Task<JToken> GetProviderInfo(string url)
    {
        var c = new HttpClient();
        var resp = await c.GetAsync(url);
        resp.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        return JToken.Parse(await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting an error message back from any of your API calls? If so, can you add that information to your question?

Comment: No there is no any error messages from API calls